# matplotlib animation does not work within a loop-executed file update

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an online plot created by `animation.FuncAnimation` which reads the data from a file and updates a figure. The code is:

```
%matplotlib notebook

from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

figure = plt.figure()
anim = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    data = open('results.txt', 'r+')
    lines = data.readlines()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
    xa = []
    ya = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
#             print(x,y)
            xa.append(float(x))
            ya.append(float(y))
    anim.clear()
    anim.scatter(xa,ya)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(figure,animate, interval = 1000)
plt.show()
```

When I manually add a point into `results.txt` it updates the figure quickly. Also I use

```
data = open('results.txt', 'a')
x = 13
data.write("%d" % x)
data.write(",")
y = 21321
data.write("%d" % y)
data.write("\n")
print (x,y)
data.close()
```

to add a new point into `results.txt`, it updates the figure. 
But, when I add points in `results.txt` through a loop (see below), it does not update the figure until when the loop is finished.

```
for i in range(100):
    data = open('results.txt', 'a')
    x = i
    data.write("%d" % x)
    data.write(",")
    y = 9*i*i
    data.write("%d" % y)
    data.write("\n")
    print (x,y)
    sleep(0.2)
    data.close()
```

I checked the file, and after each iteration of the loop, the file is getting updated, so that it should update the figure too. 
I appreciate any help or comments.

Afshin